# Intensive PHP script failing w/ "The timeout specified has expired" error / ap_content_length_filter

Tags: php

Running a MySQL intensive PHP script that is failing. Apache log reports this:

```
[Wed Jan 13 00:20:10 2010] [error] [client xxx.xx.xxx.xxxx] (70007)
The timeout specified has expired:
ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed,
referer: http://domain.com/script.php
```

Tried putting `set_time_limit(0)` at the top.

Also tried `set_time_limit(0)`

Neither fixed the timeout.

Is there some specific timeout limit I can up in `http.conf` (or elsewhere) to prevent this?

Answer (score 9):

I hit a very similar wall as well with **Apache 2.4.6** and **PHP 5.4.23 FPM/FastCGI**.

## Symptom:

No matter what I set in PHP or Apache, my script would timeout in 30 seconds and I would see the following in my Apache Error log:

> `[timestamp] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid...] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client ...] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :`

#### My VirtualHost:

```
TimeOut  300
KeepAliveTimeout 300

<IfModule reqtimeout_module>
  RequestReadTimeout header=120-240,minrate=500
  RequestReadTimeout body=120,minrate=500
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
  ProxyTimeout 300
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  FcgidConnectTimeout 300
</IfModule>
```

#### The pesky php script:

```
ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '120' );
...
ini_restore( 'max_execution_time' );
```

## The Fix: *it's a hard coded value in Apache `mod_proxy_fcgi`*

> **[Take a look at the bug report here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/bugs/429331)**

- A *patch* is available (link above)
- The fix doesn't appear to be slated for general release yet (Mar 2014)

Comment: It was fixed in 2.4.8 (2014-05-05)

Answer (score 5):

First, my solution is only applicable to the Apache Web Server.

I am working on a script meant to act as a csv download script for a report against a very very large db, and I encountered this problem too. Am NOT using php, but instead my script is written in some obscure language called heitml ;-)

The request timeout proble does occur in my scenario like this:

```
[Wed Sep 19 20:29:01 2012] [warn] [client ::1] Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /var/www/cgi-bin/heitml
[Wed Sep 19 20:29:01 2012] [error] [client ::1] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed
```

And the only serious solution I can currently adapt to is using this official timeout config extension here : [mod_reqtimeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html). It allows adjustment of timeout params like for example:

Allow 10 seconds to receive the request including the headers and 30 seconds for receiving the request body:

```
RequestReadTimeout header=10 body=30
```

Allow at least 10 seconds to receive the request body. If the client sends data, increase the timeout by 1 second for every 1000 bytes received, with no upper limit for the timeout (exept for the limit given indirectly by LimitRequestBody):

```
RequestReadTimeout body=10,MinRate=1000
```

Allow at least 10 seconds to receive the request including the headers. If the client sends data, increase the timeout by 1 second for every 500 bytes received. But do not allow more than 30 seconds for the request including the headers:

```
RequestReadTimeout header=10-30,MinRate=500
```

Usually, a server should have both header and body timeouts configured. If a common configuration is used for http and https virtual hosts, the timeouts should not be set too low:

```
RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500
```

Am yet to find out whether there's a better solution offered by Apache that doesn't require me to use an this module (assuming it's not installed by default -- though it's included in all versions 2.2.15 and later).

Answer (score 4):

I suspect I'm getting the same error, updated for a later version of Apache (2.4.16):

```
[Tue Aug 02 11:49:41.930884 2016] [core:error] [pid 28640] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] AH00574: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed, referer: https://domain.com/script.php
```

I was wondering why increasing max_execution_time in php.ini wasn't working.

For me, the fix was simply increasing the Timeout directive in httpd.conf
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout

```
Timeout 900
```

(Or in `WHM` -> `Apache Configuration` -> `Global Configuration`, as the case may be)

This timeout applies to time between IO events.  So even though the script was outputting data almost immediately, a long delay in the middle of the script's execution was causing the timeout.

Answer (score 3):

There's also the php [max_execution_time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) directive. Note that the web server's timeout settings may also be limiting your script:

> Your web server can have other timeout
> configurations that may also interrupt
> PHP execution. Apache has a Timeout
> directive and IIS has a CGI timeout
> function. Both default to 300 seconds.
> See your web server documentation for
> specific details.

Actually, this looks like an Apache error, it also effects Python scripts. Have you tried [googling it yet?](http://www.google.com/search?q=apache+70007)

Answer (score 1):

There is another timeout value placed not in php itself but in apache server. It will brake script when nothing is on output for specified time so when doing harder work in PHP you can reach this limit. Just echo anything back to browser (not buffers!) or increase apache timeout value to safe value, as far as I remember it's KeepAliveTimeOut apache property. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried all suggestions, but my problem was in the **php-fpm configuration**. I set the following line in my php-fpm configuration file:

```
request_terminate_timeout = 300s
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a timeout in the `php.ini` as well.

Comment: Yes, this was my problem.  `request_terminate_timeout = 123s` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with these resource limits in php.ini to correct the problem.

```
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 300
memory_limit = -1
```

Comment: Scratch that, it's still doing it.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  This answer is duplicated verbatim from a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/q/500467/330059).

[Original Answer](https://serverfault.com/a/746761/330059)

I have Apache 2.4.6, but the [patch](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54973) to fix it is provided in Apache >= 2.4.8.
The key here is to *start* your output immediately so that Apache (mod_proxy_fcgi) thinks the connection is active.

For example, I am using PHP and the DB query for my AJAX call takes > 30 seconds.
Because I know that the overall response will be "Content-Type: application/json", I send that header immediately.

```
#1: Start output immediately
#Note: Sending the header is innocuous
#   it can be changed later using the $replace parameter
#   (see #3)
header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );

#2: Run slow query
mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM giant_table" );

#3: Change header as needed
header( 'Content-Type: application/csv', true );

#output content
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone that may come across this. I was able to solve this by looking into memcache.

my situation:

1. a memcached server that is being used by multiple apache servers
2. memcached.sess_locking = On
3. make back to back requests on the same session (within ms of each other)

outcome:
the second requests gets stucks and times out

solution 1:
set memcached.sess_locking = Off in your php.ini

Solution 2:
decrease memcached.sess_lock_wait_min

why it works:
when a second request comes in while first one has locked the session file, the second session has to wait. If memcached.sess_lock_wait_min is set too high it just waits that long before trying to get the possession of the lock. it is super easy to test this using sess_locking = Off. If it does help you then you definitely want to play around with lock time values to see what works better for you.