# PHP output dying part way through displaying SQL table data. Also seems to effect Inserting data, looks like a limit

Tags: php, sql-server

Ok my problem is everyworks fine until I start getting some big querys and then I start getting results like this:

(heaps of listings before this)

```
CSP0525-NA/RD-XL        P7700 Adults Bizcool Splice Polo        P7700-NA/RD-XL  $34.50  0   XL  NA/Red

CSP0525-NA/WH-2XL       P7700 Adults Bizcool Splice Polo        P7700-NA/WH-2XL $34.50  0   2XL NA/White

CSP0525-NA/WH-3XL       P7700 Adults Bizcool Splice Polo        P7700-NA/WH-3XL $34.50  0   3XL
```

Note there is no colour at the end and it has stoped display any more from there (about another 200 to go. Where in the line it stops is differnet based on the search.

Memory Limit for php is 1024mb with no change to the result and the results usually come up in 2-3secs and after the timeout hit this is the error

Have adjusted the timeout settings, now the page does not time out (this is not the fault) the fault is it displays about 250 rows out of the 2000 its meant to on the page and stalls. Then it sits there doing nothing which LEADS to a timeout. In console the query works fine and displays all 2202 rows.

Thu Oct 30 13:47:50.077963 2014] [core:error] [pid 1604:tid 76] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 172.16.27.6:1215] AH00574: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed, referer: indexproducts.php

```
$sql = "SELECT DueDate, ZProductRank, PRODUCTS.Status, ProductGroup, Price11, QtyOnHand, Barcode, Barcode1, Barcode2, Barcode3, Barcode4, SupplierTitle, SupplierPartNo, UniqueID, PRODUCTS.Zsize, PRODUCTS.ZColour, PRODUCTS.ProductCode, PRODUCTS.ProductTitle FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ".$Where."
ORDER BY ProductCode  ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
$radio = "<tr><td ><a href='productsearchdetails.php?PCODE=".trim($row['ProductCode'])."&USER=".$User."&USERNO=".$Userno."'>".$Textc."".$row['ProductCode']."</a></td><td>".$Textc."".$rank."</td><td>".$Textc."".$row['ProductTitle']."</td><td>".$Textc."".date_format($row['DueDate'],'d-m-Y')."</td><td>".$Textc."".$row['SupplierPartNo']."</td><td>".$Textc."$".number_format($row['Price11'],2,'.','')."</td><td>".$Textc."".$row['QtyOnHand']."</td><td>".$Textc."".$row['Zsize']."</td><td>".$Textc."".$row['ZColour']."</td></tr>";
echo $radio;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably exhausting the memory available to PHP, and I'd guess your error log has a message to that effect. You can raise the memory limit via the ini directive 'memory_limit'.

Comment: Thanks for that, But I already increased it to 1024mb with no change, checked the phpinfo to confirm. The data displays in the first 3secs, then the browser hangs then this is the php error Thu Oct 30 13:47:50.077963 2014] [core:error] [pid 1604:tid 76] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 172.16.27.6:1215] AH00574: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed, referer: http://sql-server:99/indexproducts.php

Comment: That looks like an error coming out of the DB engine to me. Can you run the same query via the DB CLI console, and does it complete successfully?

Comment: Using SQL 2008 management it executes fine. 2208 rows in total in 3 secs

Comment: Is that the number of rows you're expecting, or is the DB engine timing out after 3 seconds and just not showing you the error on the console (and only the results it got before timeout)? I'm not really familiar with MSSQL, but many DB engines have settings to kill queries that are taking too long, maybe yours is set for 3 seconds?

Comment: Ok the query through management console completes successfully and takes 3 secs to do it, 2208 is the total rows it produces. The web page only shows about 200-300 of that. So yes the query is working fine, just not the webpage

Comment: Looks like maybe an Apache error, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054827/intensive-php-script-failing-w-the-timeout-specified-has-expired-error-ap-c

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED** Turns out the error log buffer was filling with notices that were getting produce per row and with a lot of rows it was a lot of notices, it was getting to a point that once full the php output was stopping, though I still have notices to sort out but now notice reporting is off and its working fine.