# PHPMailer end of script before header

Tags: php, hosting, phpmailer

I've done a very simple code with a form and then get this information and send and email using PHPMailer and G-suite.
I've run this code on xampp and everything is ok. It is running. But when i'm moving this to my hosting doesn't run...

PD:I've read about this error and it is maybe about files permisions but i've tried all... Setting all files to 755 and finally i've tried to set it to 777 and still not working...

I've contated with hosting providers and says that they can help me with this personal problem :/

This is my php code:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

$name="test";
$phone="test";
$email="test";

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);  
try {

$password = 'PASSWD';

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = 'email@email.com'; 
$mail->Password = $password;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl'; 


$mail->setFrom('email@email.com', 'Something');
$mail->addAddress('email@email.com');
$mail->addAddress('email@email.com'); 
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'New lead';
$mail->Body = 'Name: '.$name.'<br>Email: '.$email.'<br>Phone: '.$phone;


$mail->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

This is the only error i'm getting:

> [client IP] End of script output before headers: send.php

**PD:**

> SMTPSecure changed to tls

Still not working :(

**EDIT**
This is the errors i'm getting

> 117.03.2019 22:04:22  [client ] AH01215: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in  on line 3:
>
> 17.03.2019 22:04:34  [client ] AH01215: PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant \xe2\x80\x98display_errors\xe2\x80\x99 - assumed '\xe2\x80\x98display_errors\xe2\x80\x99' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in  on line 2:
>
> 17.03.2019 22:05:14  [client ] AH01220: Timeout waiting for output from CGI script
>
> 17.03.2019 22:05:14  [client ] AH00574: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed

**UPDATE**

I updated php to 7.3.2. PHPMailer is on 6.0.7 version. And the only different error i'm getting is this one...

> PHP Warning: Use of undefined constant \xe2\x80\x98display_errors\xe2\x80\x99 - assumed '\xe2\x80\x98display_errors\xe2\x80\x99' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /mnt/web401/c2/79/59742679/url on line 2: /home/strato/http/power/rid/26/79/59742679/url

**UPDATE 2**

- Php 7.3.2
- PHPMailer 6.0.7
- Gsuite
- Tested on XAMPP and is actually working
- Hosting on strato

Actual code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'phpmailer2/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer2/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer2/src/SMTP.php';

$name="test";
$phone="test";
$email="test";

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);  
try {

$password = 'mypassword';

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'myemail';
    $mail->Password = $password;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->setFrom('email', 'fromemail');
    $mail->addAddress('email');
    $mail->addAddress('email');

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'New lead';
    $mail->Body = 'some text';


    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

My files:

[image]

(I'm launching send2.php cause it's using last version of phpmailer[This one is located to phpmailer2])

When i execute the code i see this on screen:

> 2019-03-20 13:57:54 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()

I go to my hosting panel and i just see this

> 20.03.2019 14:55:04 my.website [client 80.38.90.0] AH01215: PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant \xe2\x80\x98display_errors\xe2\x80\x99 - assumed '\xe2\x80\x98display_errors\xe2\x80\x99' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in my.route/send2.php on line 2: my.route/send2.php
>
> 20.03.2019 14:55:44 my.website [client 80.38.90.0] AH01220: Timeout waiting for output from CGI script my.route/send2.php
>
> 20.03.2019 14:55:44 my.website [client 80.38.90.0] AH00574: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed

Comment: I don’t know if it’s the cause, but `SMTPSecure` should be `tls`, not `tsl`. I’d advise checking error logs.

Comment: @Synchro I just updated tsl to tls but still getting this error...

Comment: @Synchro As i've said on the post this code is running on localhost. But it isn't on hosting. The enterprise is not giving this kind of support to help me. I think it's their fault. And the only error i'm getting on logs is that one i posted.... Is there an other way to fix this?

Comment: You could try `SMTPDebug = 3`, but I think you have problems seeing error output. Perhaps try enabling php error display with `ini_set(‘display_errors’, true)`

Comment: @Synchro Errors updated on post

Comment: Trying that again: `ini_set('display_errors', true)`.

Comment: @Synchro I just created a new update

Answer (score 0):

`ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed` seems to be the relevant error here.

It seems the most likely culprit here is an Apache timeout being reached (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38711063/5505001) You should ask your web host if they'll allow you to change the Apache timeout temporarily to see if that's actually the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use'
```

That usually means you're running a new version of PHPMailer on a very old version of PHP. Make sure you're using at least PHP 5.5, though right now you should only be doing new development on 7.3.

```
PHP Warning: Use of undefined constant \xe2\x80\x98display_errors\xe2\x80\x99
```

That's a copy & paste error - looks like SO changed the single quotes I used into curly ones; change them back.